# Is Rx extensions suitable for reading a file and store to database

Tags: entity-framework, asynchronous, system.reactive

I have a really long Excel file wich I read using EPPlus. For each line I test if it meets certain criteria and if so I add the line (an object representing the line) to a collection. When the file is read, I store those objects to the database. Would it be possible to do both things at the same time? My idea is to have a collection of objects that somehow would be consumed by thread that would save the objects to the DB. At the same time the excel reader method would populate the collection... Could this be done using Rx or is there a better method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate answer - based on comments to my first.

Create a function returning an `IEnumberable<Records>` from EPPlus/Xls - use `yield return`
then convert the seqence to an observable on the threadpool and you've got the Rx way of having a producer/consumer and BlockingCollection.

```
function IEnumberable<Records> epplusRecords() 
{
  while (...)
     yield return nextRecord;
}
var myRecords = epplusRecords
   .ToObservable(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
   .Where(rec => meetsCritera(rec))
   .Select(rec => newShape(rec))
   .Do(newRec => writeToDb(newRec))
   .ToArray();
```

Comment: Interesting. When I have time I need to try this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your case seems to be of pulling data (`IEnumerable`) and not pushing data (`IObservable/Rx`).
Hence I would suggest LINQ to objects is something that can be used to model the solution.
Something like shown in below code.

```
publis static IEnumerable<Records> ReadRecords(string excelFile)
{
  //Read from excel file and yield values
}

//use linq operators to do filtering
var filtered = ReadRecords("fileName").Where(r => /*ur condition*/)
foreach(var r in filtered)
   WriteToDb(r);
```

NOTE: In using IEnumerable you don't create intermediate collections in this case and the whole process looks like a pipeline.

Comment: I hadn't thought about using yield, and it looks quite good now. Is this compatible with using multiple threads (for yielding the results and consuming them)?

Comment: The generation and consumption will happen on Same there in this case. Whenever you start consuming the records using foreach on the same thread the code for yield will execute

Comment: I'm seeing this. I'll do this for now and I'll continue investigating the possibility of a producer and consumer threads using a shared collection (a queue would be ideal). Thanks.

Comment: ConcurrentQueue is something that you can use for producer and consumer scenario

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like a good fit, as there's no inherent concurrency, timing, or eventing in the use case.

That said, it may be a use case for plinq. If EEPlus supports concurrent reads. Something like

```
epplusRecords
   .AsParallel()
   .Where(rec => meetsCritera(rec))
   .Select(rec => newShape(rec))
   .Do(newRec => writeToDb(newRec))
   .ToArray();
```

Comment: the other issues to consider are order-of-operations, pipelining and Excel's threading model. In this problem we know that reading data from Excel is slow and writing to the database is slow, so if the OP can read the next line from Excel while writing the current line to the database he may find a significant performance improvement. Rx can certainly do this and it will retain the order-of-operations. Using `AsParallel` to read from Excel might fail due to threading model issues - Rx won't have this issue. Rx is an excellent fit.

Comment: I re-read the question - The OP is using `EPPlus` which negates my comments about the Excel threading model. Nonetheless the order-of-operations and pipelining still apply.

Comment: The problem is that I want to have my reading method separated from my writing method... For now, I'm going with a BlockingCollection and a Producer and a Consumer threads (tasks).