# How to 'intercept' objects returned through IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mongodb

I would like to intercept/catch a reference to all objects returned from an IQueryable result so that I can later perform some work on all of those instances.

More specifically, I have a MongoDB Repository pattern which has IQueryable end points.  I would like support Saving/Updating all the entities after they have been modified.

I'm hoping for a poor man's support for something like entity framework's DbContext.Commit, without the expectation of supporting a transaction.  The thought is if I can keep a reference of all entities I can simply update them all.

How might I go about this?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164483/is-rx-extensions-suitable-for-reading-a-file-and-store-to-database   and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx

Comment: How can IObservable help?

Comment: as each object is returned you can be register a listener that is called. Thought you were thinking along those lines

Comment: @soadyp thats what I ended up doing :)  It was a new topic to me at the time, took a few to realize how to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this model;

```
 public class EntityBase 
{


    #region DB Access

    public static MongoServer GetConnection()
    {
        return MongoDBHelper.GetConnection();
    }

    public static MongoDatabase GetDatabase()
    {
        return MongoDBHelper.GetDatabase();
    }

    public static MongoCollection<T> C<T>() where T : class
    {
        MongoCollection<T> col = GetDatabase().GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name);
        return col;
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> IQ<T>() where T : class
    {
        return C<T>().AsQueryable<T>();
    }

    #endregion

}
```

some entity

```
public class SomeEntity : EntityBase 
    {
}
```

and use

```
var s = (from o in SomeEntity.IQ<SomeEntity>() select o)
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesnt really help

Comment: You can use interface or typed base db class, I can use mongo db c# offical driver. I write a base db class like  BaseDb<T> where T : EntityBase. And Save Update or delete method created. And create instance from BaseDb<SomeEntity>. After call save method. If I wrong understand your ask, you can use this model. Good luck